# Strange behaviour of caching mechanism

Tags: java

Today I got my JVM behaving really strange - at least I think so.

This is the essential part of a little cache wrapper I implemented:

```
private static final int LIMIT = (int) 10E6;

private int askedCounter = 0;
private int resolvedByCacheCounter = 0;

private HashMap<String, AlphaBetaResult> cache = new HashMap<String, AlphaBetaResult>();

public AlphaBetaResult lookup(Board board) {
    AlphaBetaResult result = this.cache.get(board.computeBoardIdentity().toString());

    this.askedCounter++;
    if (result != null) this.resolvedByCacheCounter++;

    return null; //Here is the strange part...
    //return result;
}

public void store(Board board, AlphaBetaResult result) {
    if (this.cache.size() < LIMIT) {
        this.cache.put(board.computeBoardIdentity().toString(), result);
    }
}
```

I use the cache in another class to prevent some calculations being done more than once. It seems like the cache can resolve around 10% of the requests addressed to him - so I would expect an performance increasement if I comment "return null" and uncomment "return result;" above.
But what I get instead of something better than 6s is a outOfMemory-Exception after perhaps half a minute.

The code where I call the cache:

```
private AlphaBetaResult alphaBeta(Board currentBoard, int currentDepth, int alpha, int beta) {
    AlphaBetaResult cachedResult = this.cache.lookup(currentBoard);
    if (cachedResult != null) {
        return cachedResult;
    }

    AlphaBetaResult result = alphaBetaInner(currentBoard, currentDepth, alpha, beta);

    this.cache.store(currentBoard, result);

    return result;
}
```

I really do not understand why that happens! Is this some mighty JVM optimization or am I just missing something?

**Update:** Depending on the parameters I am storing a lot of objects in the cache. With the parameters used in here I do not reach the upper end of the cache - after completing computation cache.size() says something around 400k objects. But the amount of items in the cache doesn't differ from returning null or returning result... I really don't get it

Comment: How many objects you stored in the cache?

Comment: please add alphaBetaInner func logic.

Comment: You don't need to use strings as keys, just define `hashCode` and `equals` on `Board`. It will be clearer in the code, and will require less memory if your current strings are long (which is most likely the case as you must have up to 1 million different strings as keys)

Comment: I guess alphaBetaInner function logic will be of no use because it doesn't depend on the value received from the cache - it would be to much code for the question :)

Comment: @Dici: I did that before, but the Board instances are quite big, so the String is smaller.

Comment: @FlorianLoch only the reference is stored (an integer), not the object and its content

Comment: @Dici Of course, but because the object isn't then referenced anymore it gets removed by gc, if I use it as key in my map there will remain a reference and gc will not touch the instance

Comment: @FlorianLoch could you provide the whole code on PasteBin ? I'm interested on trying to debug it

Comment: Are you sure the program runs 6 seconds and then ends normally when you return null?

Comment: @Raffaele I'm absolutely sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following JVM parameters, and run your application again to get the heap dump.

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=PATH
```

Note that the `PATH` is the location you want to generate the dump file.

Download MAT from [here](http://eclipse.org/mat/), open the generated dump file that is something like `java_pidxxxx.hprof` in MAT. And you may find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bug may be in `board.computeBoardIdentity()` and/or how you use and reuse the cached objects (are there recursive methods involved?). The behavior that your program exhibits suggests that your object *should not be cached*: if the bug is in the objects themselves or in client code we can't tell without knowing more - but the sure thing is that reusing `AlphaBetaResult` makes your program do way more operations (it lasts longer) and then crash.

Also, your cache implementation is quite naive: for example items never expire - and even if you put a limit (hardcoded) it might become a problem. I suggest you look at [other simple caches](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained). You may also specify an initial size for the cache if the input size is known to avoid rehashing.